# Excel VBA - Objtdict.Keys Produces an error when range is changed

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to generate an Unique list from a column. My Code works fine when the range is B1:B but when it is changed to B17:B it produces NA's and outputs the values in irrelevant Rows inside the column B.

Here is the Code,

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
    Dim X
    Dim objDict As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long

    Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    X = Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
    Next
    Range("B1:B" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub
```

Kindly correct me where I am going wrong. I want the output to start from the column B17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have resize the destination to accommodate the keys. You are getting away with it when B1 is B1 because `"B1:B" & objDict.Count` resizes correctly. You could add 16 to that like `"B17:B" & objDict.Count + 16` or just use resize.

```
Range("B1").Resize(objDict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
Range("B17").Resize(objDict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transpose Dictionary keys because they are only 1 dimensional, while Transposing supposes having 2 dimensional Variant. You need to assign those keys to a variant, make it 2 dimensional, and transpose them yourself. Or  just assign one by one into cells

Comment: Can you help me better? I cannot understand why it works when it is B1:B and not B17:B. Any coded examples? will help me understand better. Thanks

Comment: If you do not transpose a 1-D array when filling multiple rows of a single column you will end up with all if the cells containing the first element of the array. Transposing is not necessary if filling multiple columns of a single row with a 1-D array but that is what `Application.Transpose` is all about.